# 'Product rule' when $f$ differentiable at $c,$ and $g$ not differentiable at $c$, but $f(c)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

If you have some functions mapping $\mathbf{R}^n$ to $\mathbf{R},$ say, $f(c)=0$ and $f$ is differentiable at $c,$ $g$ continuous at $c$, can we say that the derivative is still $f'(c)g(c)$ and basically use the product rule to get the correct result despite the fact the product rule is not really defined for this case?

(From Apostol's Mathematical Analysis, trying to solve this problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h'(c)=\lim_{x\to c} \frac{h(x)-h(c)}{|x-c|}=\lim_{x\to c} \frac{h(x)}{|x-c|}=\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)}{|x-c|}\cdot g(x)=\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)}{|x-c|}\cdot \lim_{x\to c} g(x)=$

$f'(c)\cdot g(c)$ because $f(c)=0$.